# how to find max profit using demand and cost

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

so i have been stuck on this question for a while. It asks you to find out how much of each product you need to produce in order to be able to maximise profits. Now i know that Profits=Revenue-Cost.

x=quantity

Demand function is given as: $750-2p1+0.4p2$ where $p1=300$ and $p2=200$
and
$Total Cost = 22790+0.4x^2-24.2x$

I have searched online for many days and even watched various youtube videos but can still not understand how to do this. Apparently it is something to do with derivatives? if that helps?

Working out would also be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Please, use MathJax

Answer (score 0):

Take the derivative of the total cost function and set it equal to zero. Any maximum or minimum of the total cost will have a derivative equal to zero. Find the quantities of x which will produce maximum or minimum total costs by solving the equation which sets $0 = .8x - 24.2$. Then determine which of these values of x produces the smallest total cost. Since this equation only has one solution, x =  30.25 is your answer.

In this problem, your demand function is a constant value so the only goal is to minimize the total cost in order to maximize profits.